# How to upload a folder on a web server using Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I am using the Spring MVC framework to create a website. One of the features that I will need to have is the ability to upload a folder.

However, by only using Spring, I can only upload a single file or multiple files. Alternatively, I can ask the user to create a ZIP of the folder to upload, but this would be their responsibility to do that.

Is there a way to, within HTML, select a particular folder? Is there any way to copy that entire folder to a server?

Comment: I'd say you should start from sharing the code that you use to upload single files so that others can point how to modify it, if possible

Comment: There's no multi-upload built into HTML. You'll have to handle the selection in JavaScript and perform multiple uploads. You might look at some existing JavaScript components that do multi-upload to see how they handle the drop/dialog.

Answer (score -1):

you can use spring multifile feature to upload multiple file.
please refer given link , may help you to solve your problem.

```
http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-example/
```